# 'chromedriver.exe' executable may have wrong permissions

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Plz help.

What am I doing wrong here, I have checked permissions, changed path and can't get even a browser open :L

```
import os, random, sys, time
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='driver/chromedriver.exe')
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/Users/james/Documents/GitHub/LinkedIn/Scrape.py", line 5, in 
>       browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='driver/chromedriver.exe')
>     File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium-4.0.0a3-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 62, in **init**
>       service_log_path, service, keep_alive)
>     File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium-4.0.0a3-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 77, in **init**
>       self.service.start()
>     File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium-4.0.0a3-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 88, in start
>       os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
>   selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver.exe' executable may have wrong permissions. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
>   [Finished in 0.574s]
>   browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='driver/chromedriver.exe')

[code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3TRw.png)

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/immaG.png)

Comment: From the error message, it looks like you are attempting to use a **Windows** executable on a **UNIX** (Linux?) machine. You have to get chromedriver for your OS.

Comment: @DebanjanB Your linked answer is going to lead Jimmy down the wrong path. His problem is running .exe on (possibly) MacOS.

Comment: @SiKing thank you! I added .exe onto the end of it for some reason (using mac)